# HTML: How can I display an image using just its hex representation

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to put binary image data into html markup and then get the image displayed as usual in any browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429934/is-it-possible-to-put-binary-image-data-into-html-markup-and-then-get-the-image-d)

So for example I have an image like:

```
\x89PNG\r\n\u001A\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\rIHDR\u0000\u0000\u0001@\u0000\........
```

Is there any way that from that I can show the image in a img tag?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't show it natively without assistance to convert it.

If you base 64 encode it instead, you can.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBrkJggg==" alt="Base 64 encoded!" />
```

[Further Reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that with HTML only. The img tag can only display images via the URL supplied in the src attribute. You could set src to the URL of a page on your server that prints the hex string. For example:

```
<img src="myimage.php" />
```

myimage.php:

```
header("Content-type: image/png")
print $hex_string
```