# How to display jpg from db web page?

Tags: thymeleaf

I have got table and display datas from database (mysql). I use thymeleaf. All fields are ok but sb.cover doesnt show jpg (blob column in my database). Have you got any ideas how to put jpg in web page using thymeleaf? Thanks

```
<tr th:each="sb, poz : ${product}">
    <td th:text="${poz.count}">1</td>
    <td th:icon="${sb.cover}"></td>
    <td th:text="${sb.title}"></td>
    <td th:text="${sb.price}"></td>
    <td ><b><a th:href="@{/details}">DETAILS</a></b></td>
    <td ><b><a th:href="@{/cart}">ADD TO CART</a></b></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 6):

It's worked for me:

```
<img class="info" th:attr="src=@{${image}}" />
```

where 'image' is base64 image:

image = "data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhlgCWAMQAAPz.........

in Spring Java Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get_goods_detail", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getGoodsDetail(@RequestParam(value = "itemid") final int itemid,
                             ModelMap model) {
    // get image
    String image = "data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhlgCWAMQAAPz8/N3d3eX.../big image

    model.addAttribute("image", image);
    return  "goods_detail";  // return name of html view with thymeleaf
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this will help you...

```
<tr th:each="sb, poz : ${product}">
    <td th:text="${poz.count}">1</td>
   <td><img  th:attr="src=@{${sb.cover}} , title=#{background}, alt=#{background}" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" /></td> 
    <td th:text="${sb.title}"></td>
    <td th:text="${sb.price}"></td>
    <td ><b><a th:href="@{/details}">DETAILS</a></b></td>
    <td ><b><a th:href="@{/cart}">ADD TO CART</a></b></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do some thing like this:-
`<img  th:src="@{'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+${sb.encodedString}}" />`

where **encodedString** is image's byte[] data converted to base64 encoded string.

This is basic html actually. Check this question: [Is it possible to put binary image data into html markup and then get the image displayed as usual in any browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429934/is-it-possible-to-put-binary-image-data-into-html-markup-and-then-get-the-image)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can display image like below:

```
<img th:if="*{photo != null}" th:src="@{'data:image/jpg;base64,' + *{T(org.springframework.util.Base64Utils).encodeToString(photo)}}"/>
```

Comment: Lytvyn - Thank you for this answer. It is very useful and working solution!

Answer (score -1):

this method that converts the bytearray to base64 String so you can convert your product cover to base64  sring.
you need to add in the product class :

```
    public String generateBase64Image()
{
    return Base64.encodeBase64String(this.getCover());
}
```

in the web page you need to call the metho generateBase64Image() in in your web page :

```
 <img th:src="@{'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+${product.generateBase64Image()}}"  />
```

Comment: Please add some more information such that others can learn from it