# Spring : How to show image in thymeleaf from database

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I'm doing project with Spring Boot+Spring Data+Spring MVC.I want to show image from database to thymeleaf but image not displayed. This is my code

```
 <span th:each="room,iterStat : ${room}">
                    <div class="col-md-3 md-col">
                        <div class="col-md">
                            <a href="single.html" class="compare-in"><img th:src="@{/static/images/${room.image}}" alt="" />

                            </a>    
                            <div class="top-content">
                                <h5><a href="single.html"><tr th:text="${room.name}"></a></h5>
                                <div class="white">
                                    <a th:href="@{/room/{id}/book(id=${room.id})}" class="hvr-shutter-in-vertical hvr-shutter-in-vertical2">BOOK</a>
                                    <p class="dollar"><span class="in-dollar">$</span><span>2</span><span>0</span></p>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>                          
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     </span>
```

I save image with name image in database and i save image in folder ../static/images .. When I copy images name in database instead of **${room.image}** , image will display..I don't know why

Comment: Pleased help me

Comment: Do you read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772857/how-to-display-jpg-from-db-web-page)?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue, I get the issue resolved by doing this :--

```
<th:style="'background-image:url('+ ${room.image}+');'"></div>
```

Hope it helps.