# How to properly show profile picutre for user

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, h2

It seems that my Google-fu has failed me since I can't find similiar problems or solutions.
I want to show users image in the users profile page, but the image eather does not load or just consumes everything else.

The profile picture is save as such:

```
   @Lob
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private byte[] profilePicture;
```

This the controlle which should return the image. The HttpServeltResponse is something I found related to this, but I made the image consume the whole page.

```
    @GetMapping("/profile")
    public String showporfile(Model model, Principal principal, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        acc = accountRepo.findByUsername(principal.getName());
        model.addAttribute("accountName", acc.getName());
        model.addAttribute("skills", acc.getSkills());
        model.addAttribute("accounts", acc);

        /*response.setContentType("image/jpg");

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(acc.getProfilePicture());
        IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());*/

        return "profile";
    }
```

And this is my HTML in which I have tried to get the picture to show. At the moment I get error stating: The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing). It seems that the image is now going as: http://localhost:8080/[B@1c535b01 and I don't know why that is.

```
        <div th:each="account : ${accounts}">
            <label th:text="${account.name}"></label>
            <div class="header_image clearfix">
                <img th:src="${account.profilePicture}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thank you for advance I have been stuck with this for 3 days now.

**EDIT**
the image is stored to h2 database and linked to user as seen up.

Comment: I found a kind of solution finally, feels silly since I just asked this. I replaced the HTML <img.../> to <img th:src="@{'data:image/jpg;base64,' + *{T(org.springframework.util.Base64Utils).encodeToString(account.profilePicture)}}"/>  And now the image shows correctly, but I am not sure this is the way proper way of doing this.
source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772857/how-to-display-jpg-from-db-web-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you have to understand is that `src` attribute of the `img` tag is the **URL** of the image, and not the image itself.
Given you've already decided to store the image in a database, you'll need to create a separate endpoint to get the image (e.g. "/profile/avatar") where you actually return the image body pretty much the same way you're trying in your commented-out code. And then you would refer to that endpoint in your `img src`.

BTW, Actually there is a way to embed an image into html using "data" protocol and base64 encoding ([here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html) one example of it), but it's only suitable for tiny images, and I believe you would benefit from learning the usual way first.