# How to add GIF to email with a link

Tags: email, hyperlink, animated-gif

I'm wondering if it's possible to add an embedded GIF with a link to an email.

It's easy to add a GIF and it's easy to add a link on text, but I can't figure out how to add a GIF with a link on the GIF to an email.

I tried searching online but couldn't find anything that would help...

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I’m trying to link to someone’s answer from another question, hopefully this will work:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2429959/6147663

Comment: Thanks Brian for your help. It's related but doesn't exactly answer my question. It doesn't talk about adding link to an image. It's somewhat easy to add an image or GIF to an email, but adding a link to it proves to be somewhat difficult for me.

Comment: Hi, maybe you want mailto link:  <a href=“mailto:user@example.com”> ... </a> where you put the image link inside of the mailto link?

Comment: I appreciate your help, Brian. Thanks for trying. I'm looking to add a link into an email not a link in an HTML page to an email address. Maybe my original question wasn't clear.