# Generate image from backend data stream in react front end

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a react.js project and need to display an image using the `<img>` tag.

I have an endpoint to get the image.

I can see the image is loading in the network tab like this.

[image]

Even though the preview section is like this if I console log the response payload it has a data property with strange symbols which I believe is the image.

[image]

How do I generate a file in the front end to pass the `src` attribute of the `img` tag.

Comment: I would rather update backend to send URL to image instead of large binary data but your question is probably similiar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429934/is-it-possible-to-put-binary-image-data-into-html-markup-and-then-get-the-image).

Comment: Why are you loading the image with axios in the first place? Why not simply set the URL as src of the <img>?

Answer (score 0):

The response payload is an base64 image. You can show image like following:

```
render(){
    {this.state.image ? <img src={`data:image/png;base64,${this.state.image}`}/>: ''}
}
```